# Retrieving OU's from Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I am trying to fetch a list of OU's from active directory.  Unfortunately my search always ends up without any results even though I know there are 2 OU's inside the "myApp" domain component.

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myServer:1111/DC=myApp,DC=myDomain,DC=com", Username, Password)) {
    using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher()) {
        searcher.SearchRoot = entry;
        searcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=Organizational-Unit)";
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");

        //foo never gets results.  :(
        var foo = searcher.FindAll();
    }
}
```

I tried following the code in a previous StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906172/active-directory-list-ous), but, without luck.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this. It retrieve all OUs in dictionary name with path, just change SearchScope properly.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetOUInfo(SearchScope eSearchScope)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> retValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry oDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myServer:1111/DC=myApp,DC=myDomain,DC=com", Username, Password);
            DirectorySearcher oDirectorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(oDirectoryEntry,
                "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)", null, eSearchScope);

            SearchResultCollection oSearchResultCollection = oDirectorySearcher.FindAll();
            foreach (SearchResult item in oSearchResultCollection)
            {
                string name = item.Properties["name"][0].ToString();
                string path = item.GetDirectoryEntry().Path;
                retValues.Add(path, name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return retValues;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you sure of the base search `"DC=myApp,DC=myDomain,DC=com"` ? Is `"myApp"` a domain component ?

2) Can you try to specify the search scope ?

```
searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
```

3) `"(objectCategory=Organizational-Unit)"` is a shortcut understood by Active-Directory, but in fact the objectCategory attribute is a distinguished name (DN) and the real value for an OU is : `CN=Organizational-Unit,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,domain root DN`.

Can you try this filter `"(objectClas=Organizational-Unit)"` which is more common to search an OU?

---

On the command line can you try this ?

```
C:\temp>ldifde -f c:\temp\out.txt -d "DC=myApp,DC=myDomain,DC=com" -r "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)"
```

Comment: 1. Yes, I simply replaced the values with some dummy text.  I took the string straight from Microsoft's AD explorer.  2. I believe `Subtree` is the default value, but, I did that anyway without any luck.  3. I tried `(objectClass=Organizational-Unit)` without luck.  For what its worth, if I keep everything the same except for my filter and change that to filter on users, I get all the users across all the OUs.

Comment: Are you sure that these objects are OUs ?

Comment: The object class is listed as: `top;organizationalUnit`.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but, I don't believe so.  I should point out that I do have a work around solution for this problem; I can just connect to the directory with the `DirectoryEntry` object and then inspect the first level children to find OU's.  I would prefer an actual query to make this happen for an (assumed) performance gain.

Comment: First, let me say thank you for sticking with the question this long; I appreciate it.  Second, I had to change a few parameters with that command (server and port), but, it gave me 2 OU results which is exactly what this directory store has.  Are you thinking my only option would be to execute this command within my application and parse the output?

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will work

```
PrincipalContext yourOU = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mycompany.com", "OU=Marketing,OU=Corporate,DC=mycompany,DC=com");
GroupPrincipal findAllGroups = new GroupPrincipal(yourOU, "*");
PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(findAllGroups);
foreach (var group in ps.FindAll())
{
Console.WriteLine(group.DistinguishedName);
}
```